# Ghost blog Failed to lookup view "index"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ghost-blog

I run Ghost on my MAC, when i visit localhost:2368 in my browser, one issue occured:

500

Failed to lookup view "index"

Stack Trace

Failed to lookup view "index"

at deliver (/Users/zengdaqian/Documents/Ghost-0.3.3-wip/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/when/when.js:270:7)

how can i solve it? TKS!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Had the same problem, after downloading the master.zip from github. This problem ist described in the troubleshooting section on github:

> Sounds like you don't have our default theme - Casper, your content/themes/casper folder is probably empty. When cloning from Github be sure to use SSH and to run git submodule update --init. Don't use the release zip file on Github, if you want a zip file use the one from Ghost.org.

from https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

So instead of the Zip from Github, use this one: https://ghost.org/zip/ghost-0.4.2.zip

Comment: You can also do a 
    git submodule update --init
after cloning the repo to fetch the submodules

Answer (score 0):

Please check that if you have runned `grunt init` before `grunt prod`.